# Should a RESTful API provide data for an entire form?

Tags: api, rest, forms

Let's say I have a JavaScript web application which entirely uses a RESTful API for data.

Let's say this application has a data form, and let's say I'm editing a record at /product/12345. When building the form, I make a RESTful request to /product/12345 and get JSON data:

```
{
  "id": 12345,
  "name": "Some Product",
  "active": true,
  "sales_user_id": 27
}
```

*So, my form obviously may have a dropdown list for selecting a sales person. I need to populate this list.* **Where should the data come from?** What's the most common approach?

Would it make sense to make it part of the /product/12345 request response?

```
{
  "id": 12345,
  "name": "Some Product",
  "active": true,
  "sales_user_id": 27,
  "sales_users": [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Anna Graham"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Dick Mussell"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Ford Parker"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Ferris Wheeler"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "Jo King"}
  ]
}
```

What about when creating a new record? Should my API also respond to GET /product/new, with the following?

```
{
  "sales_users": [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Anna Graham"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Dick Mussell"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Ford Parker"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Ferris Wheeler"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "Jo King"}
  ],
  "categories": [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Category 1"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Category 2"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Category 3"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Category 4"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "Category 5"}
  ],
  "etc": [ ... ]
}
```

Comment: please **never** use GET request to create something. Your endpoint should be **/product**  not **/product/new**. To create a new product you should send a PUT request to that endpoint.

Comment: This is not creating anything. This is purely a request for existing data or a template for a new, not yet saved record.

Comment: oh sorry, now i see what you mean. either way product endpoint should not be responsible for providing a template product or list-of-values for product-creation form drop-downs. as @Dan says just create separate endpoints and use caching headers so your browser can cache drop-down values for performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I lean towards very simple, narrowly-focused endpoints.  I would expect a request at some location like /sales_users which returns all sales users.

GET /sales_users:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "name": "Anna Graham"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Dick Mussell"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Ford Parker"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Ferris Wheeler"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "Jo King"}
]
```

Similarly, if you are going to have a list of categories, I would add a separate endpoint for that.

GET /categories:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "name": "Category 1"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Category 2"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Category 3"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Category 4"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "Category 5"}
]
```

I would not build a GET /product/new.  Rather, I would build a form in your app to handle adding new products which knows the appropriate requests to populate its lists (e.g., GET /categories, GET /sales_users, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the list of salespeople is relatively static, I would think you'd want a separate API call `/salesusers` that you could call once (on form load, etc.) and save off so you don't have to re-request this data each time. Remember in REST, you are organizing your API around resources, and salespeople are logically separate resources from products.

Likewise, when calling `/product/new`, you would only want to be submitting data for a new product, which might include a sales_user id, but nothing more. Changes to a sales_user itself would be a separate call.